# Examples of "Mitzvah X was not practiced since the times of Y"

Tags: sources-mekorot, tanach, mitzvah

The book of Nehemia states that the Israelis didn't keep Succot from the times of Joshua Binun (about 1000 years, [Nehemiah.8.17](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Nehemiah.8.17?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi).

> וַיַּעֲשׂוּ כָל־הַקָּהָל הַשָּׁבִים מִן־הַשְּׁבִי סֻכּוֹת וַיֵּשְׁבוּ בַסֻּכּוֹת **כִּי לֹא־עָשׂוּ מִימֵי יֵשׁוּעַ בִּן־נוּן כֵּן בְּנֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל עַד הַיּוֹם הַהוּא** וַתְּהִי שִׂמְחָה גְּדוֹלָה מְאֹד׃
> The whole community that returned from the captivity made booths and dwelt in the booths—the Israelites **had not done so from the days of Joshua son of Nun to that day** and there was very great rejoicing.

I also recall that the Torah mentions that they didn't circumcise for 40 years in the desert.

What are some additional examples of Mitzvos that are mentioned as "not practiced for a long period of time"?

Comment: Doesn't mean "they hadn't done sukkot as all", it means "they hadn't had that great of a sukkot since ..." Similar line about king Yoshiyahu's Passover. (They'd been doing Passover sacrifices for hundreds of years, but his was the most special in a very long time because he'd cleaned up the idolatry.)

Comment: Note that many commentators explain this verse in a way that strongly limits the simple reading (i.e. Not that they didn't do the Mitzvah, just that it hasn't been done with as much fervor since the days of Yehoshua, etc.)

Comment: Tying tekhelet on tzitzit wasn't performed for around 1500 years.

Comment: Korban Tamid wasn't performed for 70 years. And then again not for ~2000 years.

Comment: I remember hearing that the reason there is a dispute as to the order of parshiyos in tefillin is because tefillin was outlawed and too dangerous to wear, leading to a break in the practical mesorah.